# Plotting a degrading consine function in MatPlotLib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, trigonometry

I'm looking for an efficient method to create two NumPy arrays; the first is a series of evenly spaced numbers and the second is the result of passing the first array data through a maths function.

The NumPy arrays will then be plotted, one as x and the other as y. I'm plotting the damped harmonic oscillations of a spring, which is given as a function of x (x is time on the plot). The function is an exponentially degrading sine wave, where y on the plot is the displacement from zero:

f(x) = e^(-L . x) . a . cos(w . x)

where `L`, `a` and `w` are all constants (given by the user) and `e` is exponential. I'm currently doing it as following where `SAMPLE_TIME` and `SAMPLE_RATE` are module variables set elsewhere. I'd prefer not to iterate over the y array and was looking for a way to do it in one go.

```
# numpy arrays for x and y coords
x = np.arange(0, SAMPLE_TIME, SAMPLE_RATE)
y = np.arange(0, SAMPLE_TIME, SAMPLE_RATE)

# iterate over y array
with np.nditer(y, op_flags=['readwrite']) as arr:
    for el in arr:
        # under-damped harmonic oscillator equation
        el[...] = deflection * math.exp(-el*damping_coefficent) * math.cos(w * el)
```

Comment: What do you want to plot? `x` versus `el`? What is `y` doing in your code? Isn't `x` supposed to be used to compute `el`?

Comment: x and el are the same thing, el (element) is just the idenitfier for the elements in the x array. So x / el are used to compute y.

Comment: Not me son, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a sample solution to your problem using NumPy's vectorized approach without using any `for` loops. I choose some sample input data to produce the result. I used `np.cos` and `np.exp` to make vectorized operations as `math.exp` and `math.cos` doesn't allow them.

```
SAMPLE_TIME = 100
SAMPLE_RATE = 0.2
x = np.arange(0, SAMPLE_TIME, SAMPLE_RATE)
deflection = 20
damping_coefficent = 0.1
w = 2*np.pi

el = deflection * np.exp(-x*damping_coefficent) * np.cos(w * x)
plt.plot(x, el)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('$f(x)$')
```

[image]

Comment: Not me son, exactly what I wanted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,1001)
L = 0.2
a = 2
w = 2
y = np.exp(-L*x) * a * np.cos(w * x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Please note that `numpy` array are vectorized, meaning that you can perform arithmetic on the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

When using `numpy` array, the operations are vectorized automatically. Following is the code you can use

```
# Create array x with length 200 and equally spaced values between 0 to 10
x = np.linspace(0,10, 200)    
y = deflection * np.exp(-x * damping_coefficient) * np.cos(w *x)
```